# C# LINQ use xml with case insensitive queries

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I was trying to use a LINQ query that will iterate through an xml document. However I wanted to either use an OR statement or a string.toLower() to make sure it will always get the data it needs

I currently have:

```cs
// read all <item> tags and put the in an array.
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
var newItems = (from story in xml.Descendants("item")
    select new Feed
    {
        Title = ((string) story.Element("title")),
            Link = ((string) story.Element("link")),
            Description = ((string) story.Element("description")),
            PublishDate = ((string) story.Element("pubDate")),
    }
).Take(20).ToList();
```

what I still want to change:

1. (E.G.) `Title = ((string)story.Element("title"))` needs to search case insensitive.
2. `from story in xml.Descendants("item") select new Feed` needs to search in item as well as in entry (both case-insensitive).

PS: as I am iterating through the an RSS document I cannot directly access the XML document.

thanks for input.

Comment: "`((string)story.Element("title"))` need to search case insansitive" Does this mean you have both `title` and `Title` in your xml? I don´t understand what you mean by search case-insensitive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive XML parser in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334771/case-insensitive-xml-parser-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @HimBromBeere, that no matter whether its title or TiTle it returns the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aways create extension methods for that. Here is the class that I normally use:

```
public static class XElementExtensions {
    public static bool EqualsIgnoreCase(this XName name1, XName name2) {
        return name1.Namespace == name2.Namespace &&
            name1.LocalName.Equals(name2.LocalName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public static XElement GetChild(this XElement e, XName name) {
        return e.EnumerateChildren(name).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<XElement> EnumerateChildren(this XElement e, XName name) {
        return e.Elements().Where(i = > i.Name.EqualsIgnoreCase(name));
    }
}
```

Then, you can change your code to something like this:

```
var newItems = (from story in xml.Root.EnumerateChildren("item")
select new Feed
{
    Title = ((string) story.GetChild("title")),
        Link = ((string) story.GetChild("link")),
        Description = ((string) story.GetChild("description")),
        PublishDate = ((string) story.GetChild("pubDate")),
}).Take(20).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

XML is typically defined by a schema - it should have a fixed format for the element names - so `title` *isn't* the same as `TiTlE` in XML terms. I don't think it's possible to do what you want, using `.Element`

Comment: yes I found that as well however different RSS have different schedules so  thought instead of making 3 queries, I'll see whether anyone has ever found a solution to this.

Comment: There probably are ways to do it - e.g. convert all of the XML tags to upper-case before starting. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334771/case-insensitive-xml-parser-in-c-sharp