# Handling Different XML Element Names for Serialization and Deserialization in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I need advice on handling XML serialization and deserialization in C#. My issue is that I receive XML with elements starting with uppercase letters (e.g., `<Id>`) for deserialization, but I need to get lowercase letters (e.g., `<id>`) for serialization.

Is there a way to handle these naming differences, other than xslt or custom serializer?

Example class:

```cs
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Invoice")]
public class Invoice
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "User-id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    
    // more properties

}
```

**Edit**

My case

I need to read xml from db with first letters big

`<Invoice><Id>1</Id><User-id>1</User-id></Invoice>`

In the tags and pass it in the body request but with lowercase letters in the tags

`<invoice><id>1</id><user-id>1</user-id></invoice>`.

Comment: You named things backwards.  The XmlElement ElementName must match case (upper/lower) in the xml file.  The property name in the class can be any name like how you plan to use the property.

Comment: So you need to serialize to a different xml schema than the one you deserialize from?

Comment: yes, the schema difference is only in case @ZoharPeled

Comment: I wrote it this way because I thought it would be more understandable. I corrected it. @jdweng

Comment: Don't you want the class name for id to be lowercase?  The elementname and class name should be different.

Comment: @Hub you can do pre-processing of the XML before de-serialisation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9335670/3728624

Comment: @EdgarsPivovarenoks If there is no other, 'easier' way than xslt or custom serializer, I want to make xslt

Comment: @jdweng I don't understand exactly what you're writing about

Comment: You said "I need to use lowercase letters (e.g., <id>)" which means the class name should be "id" and the ElementName should be "Id".  ElementName must match the case of the XML file.

Comment: @jdweng my mistake, it's already improved. The name element matches the object I get, like `Id`, but I want the names to start with lowercase letters when serializing. If I use a lowercase letter (`id`), the object will not be created correctly

Comment: ElementName is used to read and write the xml file and must match the tag names in the Xml data.  The class name "public int Id" can be anything you want.

Comment: @jdweng but I don't mean the property/class name, but the name in the tag or i still dont understand you. I want one model to be able to operate on two different tag formats.

Comment: Maybe there is a library that has different attributes for reading and writing, or maybe something else.

Comment: @jdweng In edit of question I paste my case.

Comment: You could use a custom xmlWriter to serialize (or reader to deserialize) or xslt to tranform the outgoing xml, or duplicate the class with different attributes, but I don't see a better way to do it. Then again, it's been forever since I've had to work with XML serialization.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a good solution for everyone,
in the RestSharp library I found attributes such as

```cs
[DeserializeAs(Name = "...")]
[SerializeAs(Name = "...")]
```

In my case it look like this

```cs
    [SerializeAs(Name = "invoice")]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Invoice")]
    public class invoice
    {
        [SerializeAs(Name = "id")]
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id")]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [SerializeAs(Name = "user-id")]
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "User-id")]
        public int userId { get; set; }

        // more properties

    }
```

from this model i get xml like

```xml
<invoice>
  <id>1</id>
  <user-id>1</user-id>
</invoice>
```

For this to work, there are requirements

```cs
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "...")]
 [XmlElement(ElementName = "...")]
```

Comment: Seems like a solid solution designed specifically for this kind of problem. I'm glad you've found your answer.